# Importrange from xls

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I aware for `importrange` the formula is:

```
IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)
// like
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hh2grfB6rp9OQ2yAIu3S5YF_CCFJGwyqPGveABlOZKg/edit", "World Cup!A1:D21")
```

But I wonder if there is a way to import range from online XLS sheet, I've the below link, can I import it into my google sheets:

```
https://www.customs.gov.sa/themes/custom/customs/json/tariff_en.xlsx
```

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. importrange works only with google sheet format.

Comment: Due to the limitations of Custom functions, pre-convert XLSX to Sheets via Apps Script works for you?

Comment: @JoseVasquez did not get your point, can you clarify pls, can we pre-convert the sheet in the link before opening it?

Comment: Sure, what I actually wanted to ask is, let's say we have a Google Apps Script which converts XLSX to Google Sheets format and then your Spreadsheet makes use of this copy of the original XLSX (Google Sheets format now), is it viable given your case? Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: @JoseVasquez yes it is, appreciate to show mw how to do it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can create another Spreadsheet previously and then import the range

Here's my approach:

First convert your XLSX to a Spreadsheet:

```
function xlsxToSheets() {
  // This URL should always be the XLSX
  const url = "https://www.customs.gov.sa/themes/custom/customs/json/tariff_en.xlsx"
  var xlsx = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("XLSX import");
  Drive.Files.update({}, ss.getId(), xlsx.getBlob(), {
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
  });
  
  Logger.log(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/edit`);
}
```

The code above will print the new Spreadsheet URL in order to be copied and then pasted into an `IMPORTRANGE` sheet function.

Having said that, you will need to import the sheet like:

```
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/edit", "Sheet!A:H")
```

**Note: The URL you provided is no longer accesible but this answer is still valid for another XLSX**